# How easy (or otherwise) is it to to tune a database AFTER 'going LIVE'?

Tags: mysql, database-design, database-tuning

It is looking increasingly like I'll have to go live before I have had the time to tweak all the queries/tables etc, before I go live with a website (already 6 months behind schedule, so all though this is not the ideal scenario - thats how things are).

Its now a case of having to bite the bullet. Its just a case of trying to work out how big that bullet will be when we come to 'biting it'. Once the databse goes live obviously we cant change the data on a whim, because its live data. I am fairly confident on the most of db schema - for e.g. the tables are in most 3 and 4th normal form, and constraints are used to ensure data integrity. I have also put in some indexes on some column that (*I think*) will be used a lot in queries though this was done quite hurridly and not tested - this is the bit I am worried about.

To clarify, I am not talking about wholesale structure change. The tables themselves are unlikely to change (if ever), however it is almost guaranteed that I will have to tune the tables at some stage (either personally or by hiring someone).

I want to know how much of a task this is. Specifically, assuming a database of a few gigabytes (so far roughly 300 tables)

Assuming 50% of the tables need tuning in the next few months:

1. How long will it take to perform the tuning (I know this is a "how long is a piece of string" type question) - but what are the main determinants of the effort required, so I can work out how long it is likely to take?
2. Is it possible to either lock sections of the database, (or specific tables) whilst the indexes are being reworked, or does the entire databse need to go offline? (I am using mySQL 5.x as the db)
3. Is what I describe (going live before ALL tables perfectly tuned) outrageously risky/inadvisable ? (Does it justify the months of sleepless nights this has caused me so far) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try at least to quantify the limits of the database before *going live*, so that at least you would know when the activity generated from your application is getting near to that threshold.

You may want to simulate (automatically as much as possible) the typical usage of the database from your application, and check how many concurrent users/sessions/transactions, etc it can handle before it breaks. This, at least, should allow you to solve the "sleepless nights" issue.

As for the original "How easy is it...?" question, the answer obviously depends on many factors. However, the above analysis would undoubtedly help, as at the very least you will be in a position to say whether your database requires tweaking or not.

Comment: Daniel: could you please clarify (perhaps with an example or a url),, what you mean by (1). "quantify the capacity limits of the database" and (2). Regarding the "stress testing" you mention, its a VERY, VERY good idea. Are there any utils or anything like that I can use to stress test the web application (that will definitely help me sleep better at night!). I am using the Symfony frame work if that helps.

Comment: @Stick it...: By "quantifying the limits" I simply meant to identify what causes a stess-test to break. For example, if you are building a Stack Overflow clone, you can create some basic simulators that simulate the typical usage of the site: A thread that reads from the database, another thread that posts random questions and answers, another thread that submits random votes, etc. Then you would be able to increase the frequency of those operations until something breaks.

Comment: (cont)...  For example you might find out that if you viewing the main page many times per second, new questions/answers might block because of some lock-contention. Finding this out, and find that it happens at 500 hits per second is very valuable, as it allows you to act in a systematic manner.

Answer (score 2):

In general it is much harder to fix a poor database design that is causing performance issues after going live becasue you have to deal with the existing records. Even worse, the poor design may not become apparent until months after going live when there are many records instead of a few. This is why databses should be designed with performance in mind (no this is not premature optimization, there are known techniques which generally perform better than other techniques and they shoulod be considered inthe design) and databases should be tested against a test set of records that is close to or more than the expected level of records you would have after a couple of years.

As to how long it will take to completely fix a badly designed database, months or years. Often the worst part is something that is central to the design (like say an EAV table) and which will require almost every query/sp/view. UDF to be adjusted to move to a better structure. You then have to ensure all records are moved to the new better structure. The sooner you can fix a mistake like this the better. Far better to move a couple of thousand records to a new structure than 100,000,000.

If your structure is ok but your queries are bad, you are better off as you can take the top ten worst performing (Choose based not just on total time to run but time X no of times run) and fix, rinse and repeat.

If you are in the midst of fixing a poor database, this book might come in handy:

[http://www.amazon.com/Refactoring-Databases-Evolutionary-Database-Design/dp/0321293533/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1268158669&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321293533)

Answer (score 1):

To answer the title question, I'd say it's fairly easy to tune your DB after deploying into Production.

It's a great idea to be improving performance after deploying to any environment. Being Production adds a bit of pressure, along with the schedule. I'd suggest deploying to Prod, and let it perform as it will. Then start measuring:

- how long to run Report X in different times (peak vs after-hours, if there is such a concept in your app).
- what's the user's experience when using the app for those critical use-cases?

Then take a backup of your Prod environment, and create yourself a pre-Prod environment. There you'll be able to run your upgrade scripts to be able to measure the 'how long' type questions you have. Index creation, upgrade down-times, etc. When tuning queries, etc, you'll have a great idea of how it performs with production data & volumes. Granted, you won't have the benefits of having those users performing those inserts at the same time.

Keep that backup for multiple iterations, failed upgrades, new/unprepared-for issues, etc.

Keep making backups after each deployment, so that you can test the next round of improvements to your DB.

Answer (score 1):

1. It depends on what you're tuning. Let's say you're adding an index to a couple tables, or changing a table type from MyISAM to InnoDB or something, then with a large enough table, those things could be done in 5 to 10 minutes depending on your hardware. It won't take hours. That said, it's still best to do any live-db tuning in the middle of the night.
2. You can grab a read lock by calling `FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK` but it's probably better to put up a "we're doing maitenance" message in your app for the 15-30 mins you're doing it, just to be safe.
3. The risk is inherent to the situation and what happens if there are serious problems. I usually take a more cowboy approach and take stuff live, especially if they aren't under high load so I can easily find pain points and fix them. If this is a mission critical system, then no, load test or whatever you can first to be sure you're as ready as you can be. Also, keep in mind that you cannot foresee all the issues you'll have. If your indexes are good, then you're probably okay to take it live and see what needs to be worked on.